# Problem with identical metrics results after machine learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sql-injection

When trying machine learning on a dataset, I got the same results for metrics such as accuracy and F-score on different machine learning algorithms.

I have a dataset on which I trained my chosen algorithms. I found it on the Kaggle website: [source](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/evg3n1j/httpparamsdataset).

Here are code snippets from the Jupiter file, and the results of their execution:

## List of connected libraries

**IN:**

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import joblib
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import models, layers
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

## Loading dataset

**IN:**

```
df = pd.read_csv("payload_mini.csv",encoding='utf-16')
df.head(10)
```

## Load, process and split the data for further training of the classification model

**IN:**

```
df = pd.read_csv("payload_mini.csv",encoding='utf-16')

df = df[(df['attack_type'] == 'sqli') | (df['attack_type'] == 'norm')]

X = df['payload']
y = df['label']

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df = 2, max_df = 0.8, stop_words = stopwords.words('english'))
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(X.values.astype('U')).toarray()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)
print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
print(y_test.shape)
```

**OUT:**

```
(8040, 1585)
(8040,)
(2011, 1585)
(2011,)
```

## Naive Bayes Classifier

**IN:**

```
nb_clf = GaussianNB()
nb_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = nb_clf.predict(X_test)
print(f"Accuracy of Naive Bayes on test set : {accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test)}")
print(f"F1 Score of Naive Bayes on test set : {f1_score(y_pred, y_test, pos_label='anom')}")
print("\nClassification Report:")
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

**OUT:**

```
Accuracy of Naive Bayes on test set : 0.9806066633515664
F1 Score of Naive Bayes on test set : 0.9735234215885948

Classification Report:
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

        anom       0.97      0.98      0.97       732
        norm       0.99      0.98      0.98      1279

    accuracy                           0.98      2011
   macro avg       0.98      0.98      0.98      2011
weighted avg       0.98      0.98      0.98      2011
```

## Random forest algorithm:

**IN:**

```
rf_clf = RandomForestClassifier()
rf_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred_rf = rf_clf.predict(X_test)
print(f"Accuracy of Random Forest on test set : {accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test)}")
print(f"F1 Score of Random Forest on test set : {f1_score(y_pred, y_test, pos_label='anom')}")
print("\nClassification Report:")
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred_rf))
```

**OUT:**

```
Accuracy of Random Forest on test set : 0.9806066633515664
F1 Score of Random Forest on test set : 0.9735234215885948

Classification Report:
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

        anom       1.00      0.96      0.98       732
        norm       0.98      1.00      0.99      1279

    accuracy                           0.99      2011
   macro avg       0.99      0.98      0.99      2011
weighted avg       0.99      0.99      0.99      2011
```

## Support vector machine

**IN:**

```
svm_clf = SVC(gamma = 'auto')
svm_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = svm_clf.predict(X_test)
print(f"Accuracy of SVM on test set : {accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test)}")
print(f"F1 Score of SVM on test set: {f1_score(y_pred, y_test, pos_label='anom')}")
print("\nClassification Report:")
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

**OUT:**

```
Accuracy of SVM on test set : 0.9189457981103928
F1 Score of SVM on test set: 0.8658436213991769

Classification Report:
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

        anom       1.00      0.76      0.87       689
        norm       0.89      1.00      0.94      1322

    accuracy                           0.92      2011
   macro avg       0.95      0.88      0.90      2011
weighted avg       0.93      0.92      0.92      2011
```

As you can see when training on different machine learning algorithms, we get the same results in the case of random forest and naive Bayesian classifier.
I hope you can help me to fix a possible bug in the code or improve it in some way.

Comment: In the random forest, the predictions are saved in `y_pred_rf`  but when showing the accuracy and f1 scores you use `y_pred` which is the wrong variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code for Random Forest, you're storing predictions as `y_pred_rf` but calling your metrics on `y_pred`